# phpmailer exception installing wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I've a problem installing wordpress, it's not a blocking problem however it has to deal with phpmailer, there is an exception saying that phpmailer class cannot be instantiated.

```
phpmailerException: Could not instantiate mail function. in /home/me/workspace/wordpress/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php on line 1375
```

The problem is not blocking but i cannot understand how to solve it.

```
object(phpmailerException)[178]
  protected 'message' => string 'Could not instantiate mail function.' (length=36)
```

The sendmail software is installed and functioning, I've never had this problem before using php so i do not have any idea about where to look at. I've found several things in the web but none related to the wordpress installation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are working in localhost?

Comment: This could be because your "to email" is invalid somehow.

Comment: It's not that it can't create a PHPMailer instance, it's that PHPMailer can't use the mail function. This is covered in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), and it's probably an auth issue. Try setting `SMTPDebug = 2` and you'll see more of what's going on.

Comment: Yes Vasim Vanzara, i'm working from localhost. I'll check the to email property in phpinfo, Synchro thanks for the link i'll check it when i'll have the time.